# Colored theorem style which does not color the name

Tags: color, thmtools

I am using a `thmtools` to color my theorems. However, I want the name of this theorems to be uncolored. Now I have :

[image]

but I want the "test" in black.

The code I use for these theorems is :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{color}


\definecolor{thmtitre}{RGB}{218,4,4}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\color{thmtitre}\normalfont\bfseries,
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    spaceabove = 6pt,
    spacebelow = 6pt,
    ]{thmstyle}

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}[test]
hey
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

and I did not find an option in `thmtools` to solve my problem

Thank you by advance !

Comment: What precisely do you want to be colored?

Comment: If want that "Theorem 1" stills colored, but the rest in black

Comment: Please: 1) Envelop your code wihtin {} ... it's not a comment. 2) Complete the code. At least we need the preamble AND the call which shows your "hey"-print. Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, I did not found the right way to write code. I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, with the `headformat` key.

Incidentally, needless to load `inputenc` with option `[utf8]`: it is what LaTeX expects by default. You don't have to load `amsfonts` either, since  `amssymb` does it for you.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{thmtitre}{RGB}{218,4,4}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\normalfont\textcolor{thmtitre}{\bfseries\NAME\,\NUMBER}\NOTE,%
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    spaceabove = 6pt,
    spacebelow = 6pt,
    ]{thmstyle}

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[test]
Successful test?
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot !

Comment: `headformat=\normalfont\textcolor{thmtitre}{\bfseries\NAME\ \NUMBER}\NOTE` (not `\,`)

Comment: @egreg: I tested first with `~` (which is approximately the same as `\ `, except it's unbreakable, if I'm not mistaken)  and found it too large, that's why I used a thin space. Of course, it's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @Bernard The space produced by `~` can be different from ``\ `` when following punctuation, otherwise they're the same; and they produce the standard spacing used everywhere. Anyway, `\normalfont` should be outside the scope of `\color` (and `\textcolor` is better).

Comment: @egreg: I've fixed the code – except the spacing: having tested, I really prefer a thin space (somewhat  like the spacing between a number and the unit).